# Successive approximations for $y''= \frac{y'^2}{y}-\frac{y}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Successive approximation:
$$\begin{align}
y_{n+1}&=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xz_n(t)\,dt\\
z_{n+1}&=z_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y_n(t),z_n(t))\,dt
\end{align}$$

I try to use it on the 2nd-order differential equation as below:

$$y''(x)= \frac{y'(x)^2}{y(x)}-\frac{y(x)}{x^2}$$
With BV: $y(1)=2,y(2)=1$

By defining $z=y'(x)$, we have: 
$$\begin{align}
z'(x)=f(x,y,z)= \frac{z^2(x)}{y(x)}-\frac{y(x)}{x^2} \\
z(1)=y'(1) \\
z(2)=y'(2)
\end{align}$$

But here z(1) and z(2) are really unknowns (not given by boundary conditions), how can we use the Successive approximation method to get the approximation say $z_2(x)$ and $y_2(x)$?

PS: I have already calculated the analytical solution to this equation already, hence this is a pure practice question on (Successive) approximation.

Comment: Use the Green kernel for $y''(x)=f(x)$ to construct the integral equation. Apart from noting that $(\ln|y(x)|)''=-\frac1{x^2}=(\ln|x|)''$.

Comment: Maybe you can solve it using the Fourier transform as differentiation and multiplication are convolution of coefficients and convolution turns into multiplication in the Fourier domain.

Answer (score 2):

let me see if we can change of variable: $$u = (\ln y)'=\frac {y'} y,\  u' = \frac{y''}y - \frac{y'^2}{y^2}.  $$ the differential equation $$ y''= \frac{y'^2}{y}-\frac{y}{x^2} $$ is transformed into $$u' + \frac{y'^2}{y^2}=\frac{y'^2}{y^2}-\frac1{x^2}\to u' = -\frac 1{x^2}\to u = \frac 1x +A\to (\ln y)' = (\ln x)' + A\to y = Bxe^{Ax}$$  now, you can find the constants $A, B$ by setting the boundary conditions $y(1) = 2, y(2) = 1.$

Comment: Thanks, but I know the analytical solution already, what I want is to find (polynomial) approximation.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=ax^k$
then
$y''x=ak(k-1)x^{k-2},
y'^2/y=ak^2x^{k-2},
y/x^2=ax^{k-2}$
so
$k(k-1)=k^2+1$
or $k=-1$.

Therefore
$1/x$ is a solution.

Don't know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't use successive approximation.